# C++ Is there some way to loop through struct types in namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, typename> types;

for (typename T : Namespace) {
    types.emplace(typeid(T).name(), T);
}
```

Or is there some other way to access type in namespace using type name?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: C++ doesn't have type reflection intrinsically.